# Google Analytics within Spotify - Every call is a unique visitor

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, spotify

I'm using the google analytics framework from within Spotify with the following code:

```
googletracker = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/googletracker")
...

tracker = new googletracker.GoogleTracker("XXXXXXXXX");

...

function track(pagename) {
  if(pagename !== undefined) {
    tracker.track( pagename );
  }
}
```

The problem is, every call is handled as if it were from a unique visitor and the calls from a session aren't bundled together. But where's the problem? That's how my analytic overview looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a cookie bug, this wrapper has not been working properly.

This is now fixed in 0.8.3 but the wrapper is deprecated. You can now use the GA js directly in your app.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Comment: The new async API doesn't work either but through the old API which is still available GA finally works.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the actual page your code is triggering on.  This is hosted on spotify?  My first guess would be maybe spotify has their own GA code that is overwriting your GA's cookies (I went to spotify.com and I do see GA code popping...)

Comment: That's within a spotify app. So it's a HTML5/JS app hosted in the desktop client from spotify.